# how to find how many rows were merged by one day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a dataframe

```py
tickers                        dt  AAPL  AMC  AMZN  ...  TH  TSLA  VIAC  WKHS
0       2021-03-19 15:11:11+00:00     0    0     0  ...   0     0     0     0
1       2021-03-22 12:43:45+00:00     0    0     0  ...   0     0     0     0
2       2021-03-22 13:07:46+00:00     0    0     0  ...   0     1     0     0
3       2021-03-22 13:55:05+00:00     0    0     0  ...   0     2     0     0
4       2021-03-23 04:59:01+00:00     0    0     0  ...   0     0     0     0
..                            ...   ...  ...   ...  ...  ..   ...   ...   ...
835     2021-07-29 23:05:30+00:00     0    0     0  ...   0     0     0     0
836     2021-07-30 01:52:35+00:00     0    0     1  ...   0     0     0     0
```

I want to merge the whole data frame by 1 day. After that I want to divide each merged number for each column by the number of rows that were in each day.
I tried merging

```
bullish_comments_df1 = bullish_comments_df1.resample('1D').sum()
```

but then I don't know how to divide by the number of rows that were merged in each day
Thank you for help

Comment: Dividing the sum by the count is equivalent to taking the mean, no?

Comment: Do you wish to group by date and take average. i.e each day mean

Comment: yeah I want to have same dataframe but aggregated by day and then divide each row number by the rows that were aggregated. so each row aggregated would have different number since there are different numbers of rows in each day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resampling by day buy using the mean instead of sum and count.

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['dt'])

df.resample('1D').mean()

                                AAPL  AMC  AMZN   TH  TSLA  VIAC  WKHS
dt                                                               
2021-03-19 00:00:00+00:00   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
2021-03-20 00:00:00+00:00   NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2021-03-21 00:00:00+00:00   NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2021-03-22 00:00:00+00:00   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0
2021-03-23 00:00:00+00:00   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
```

Days without samples can be removed using `dropna`:

```
df.resample('1D').mean().dropna(axis=0, how='all')

                           AAPL  AMC  AMZN   TH  TSLA  VIAC  WKHS
dt                                                               
2021-03-19 00:00:00+00:00   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
2021-03-22 00:00:00+00:00   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0
2021-03-23 00:00:00+00:00   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
```

Hope it serves

Comment: it gives me nan and not NaN and i want to convert it to 0

Comment: You can fill those using `df.fillna(value=0)`

Comment: could you share your output?